# select clause with substring and charindex, or all fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string with this structure:

```
433962/9263089/DC
```

I'm using `substring` and `charindex` to find the characters embedded between the bars of the string. This works:

```
SUBSTRING(sk.skcontenedor,CHARINDEX('/',sk.skcontenedor)+1, 
CHARINDEX('/',sk.skcontenedor,CHARINDEX('/',sk.skcontenedor)+1)
-CHARINDEX('/',sk.skcontenedor)-1) as 'Substring'
```

I want to put this code in the `SELECT` clause, like so:

```
select 
    SUBSTRING(sk.skcontenedor,CHARINDEX('/',sk.skcontenedor)+1, 
    CHARINDEX('/',sk.skcontenedor,CHARINDEX('/',sk.skcontenedor)+1)
    -CHARINDEX('/',sk.skcontenedor)-1) as 'Substring' 
from skcontenedor sk
join SKCONTENEDORDETALLE skcd (nolock) on sk.skcontenedorid=skcd.skcontenedorid
where DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, skcd.SkContenedorLineaFch)) between '20200318' and '20200318'
```

But I see this error:

> **Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.**

However, if I also include `',*` after my `substring` code, to show all the other fields, I see the result of the query correctly:

```
select 
    SUBSTRING(sk.skcontenedor,CHARINDEX('/',sk.skcontenedor)+1, 
    CHARINDEX('/',sk.skcontenedor,CHARINDEX('/',sk.skcontenedor)+1)
    -CHARINDEX('/',sk.skcontenedor)-1) as 'Substring'
    , * 
from skcontenedor sk
join SKCONTENEDORDETALLE skcd (nolock) on sk.skcontenedorid=skcd.skcontenedorid
where DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, skcd.SkContenedorLineaFch)) between '20200318' and '20200318'
    and sk.skcontenedororigen in ('P', 'I')
    and SKContenedorDepOrigen<>'DR'
```

What is the difference? What did I miss in the first example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to use a `case` expression:

```
(case when sk.skcontenedor like '%/%/%'
      then <your logic here>
 end)
```